# How to embed base64 images into SendGrid email via python?

Tags: python, base64, embed, html-email, sendgrid

According to [this article](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/) by Sendgrid, inline embedding (Base64 Encoding) is supported.

However the below code does not work, because it does not show the actual image, which should look like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/33qgydty/).

```
import sendgrid

html = """
<div>
    <p>Taken from wikpedia</p>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>
"""
sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient('api_key')
message = sendgrid.Mail()
message.set_html(html)
message.add_to('test@gmail.com')
message.set_from('test2@gmail.com')
message.set_subject('test subject')
print sg.send(message)
```

The email I received looks like the following: 
[image]

Comment: What email client are you using to view the email? gmail?

Comment: @JustinSteele - yep, I'm using gmail

Comment: I wonder if gmail blocks/doesn't support inline images.

Answer (score 0):

*Your code might be working*, since the `alt` attribute is being displayed.

However Gmail (and most other email clients [cannot display embedded SVG images](https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-svg/) in an email.

---

Not sure how much creative freedom you have, but you could use special characters display a red • :

```
<p>Taken from wikpedia <span style="color: red;">•</span></p>
```

or

```
<p>Taken from wikpedia <span style="color: red;">&bull;</span></p>
```